# How to stop and repeat a melody using a button?

Tags: pins, button, buzzer

How can we make our melody stop when we press the button the first time and repeat the melody when we press the button the second time?

```c
// Noterna defineras

#define NOTE_B0  31
#define NOTE_C1  33
#define NOTE_CS1 35
#define NOTE_D1  37
#define NOTE_DS1 39
#define NOTE_E1  41
#define NOTE_F1  44
#define NOTE_FS1 46
#define NOTE_G1  49
#define NOTE_GS1 52
#define NOTE_A1  55
#define NOTE_AS1 58
#define NOTE_B1  62
#define NOTE_C2  65
#define NOTE_CS2 69
#define NOTE_D2  73
#define NOTE_DS2 78
#define NOTE_E2  82
#define NOTE_F2  87
#define NOTE_FS2 93
#define NOTE_G2  98
#define NOTE_GS2 104
#define NOTE_A2  110
#define NOTE_AS2 117
#define NOTE_B2  123
#define NOTE_C3  131
#define NOTE_CS3 139
#define NOTE_D3  147
#define NOTE_DS3 156
#define NOTE_E3  165
#define NOTE_F3  175
#define NOTE_FS3 185
#define NOTE_G3  196
#define NOTE_GS3 208
#define NOTE_A3  220
#define NOTE_AS3 233
#define NOTE_B3  247
#define NOTE_C4  262
#define NOTE_CS4 277
#define NOTE_D4  294
#define NOTE_DS4 311
#define NOTE_E4  330
#define NOTE_F4  349
#define NOTE_FS4 370
#define NOTE_G4  392
#define NOTE_GS4 415
#define NOTE_A4  440
#define NOTE_AS4 466
#define NOTE_B4  494
#define NOTE_C5  523
#define NOTE_CS5 554
#define NOTE_D5  587
#define NOTE_DS5 622
#define NOTE_E5  659
#define NOTE_F5  698
#define NOTE_FS5 740
#define NOTE_G5  784
#define NOTE_GS5 831
#define NOTE_A5  880
#define NOTE_AS5 932
#define NOTE_B5  988
#define NOTE_C6  1047
#define NOTE_CS6 1109
#define NOTE_D6  1175
#define NOTE_DS6 1245
#define NOTE_E6  1319
#define NOTE_F6  1397
#define NOTE_FS6 1480
#define NOTE_G6  1568
#define NOTE_GS6 1661
#define NOTE_A6  1760
#define NOTE_AS6 1865
#define NOTE_B6  1976
#define NOTE_C7  2093
#define NOTE_CS7 2217
#define NOTE_D7  2349
#define NOTE_DS7 2489
#define NOTE_E7  2637
#define NOTE_F7  2794
#define NOTE_FS7 2960
#define NOTE_G7  3136
#define NOTE_GS7 3322
#define NOTE_A7  3520
#define NOTE_AS7 3729
#define NOTE_B7  3951
#define NOTE_C8  4186
#define NOTE_CS8 4435
#define NOTE_D8  4699
#define NOTE_DS8 4978

#define melodyPin 3
//här är noterna som är i melodin
int melody[] = {
  NOTE_E7, NOTE_E7, 0, NOTE_E7,
  0, NOTE_C7, NOTE_E7, 0,
  NOTE_G7, 0, 0,  0,
  NOTE_G6, 0, 0, 0,

  NOTE_C7, 0, 0, NOTE_G6,
  0, 0, NOTE_E6, 0,
  0, NOTE_A6, 0, NOTE_B6,
  0, NOTE_AS6, NOTE_A6, 0,

  NOTE_G6, NOTE_E7, NOTE_G7,
  NOTE_A7, 0, NOTE_F7, NOTE_G7,
  0, NOTE_E7, 0, NOTE_C7,
  NOTE_D7, NOTE_B6, 0, 0,

  NOTE_C7, 0, 0, NOTE_G6,
  0, 0, NOTE_E6, 0,
  0, NOTE_A6, 0, NOTE_B6,
  0, NOTE_AS6, NOTE_A6, 0,

  NOTE_G6, NOTE_E7, NOTE_G7,
  NOTE_A7, 0, NOTE_F7, NOTE_G7,
  0, NOTE_E7, 0, NOTE_C7,
  NOTE_D7, NOTE_B6, 0, 0
};
//tempo mario(hastigheten på tonerna)
int tempo[] = {
  12, 12, 12, 12,
  12, 12, 12, 12,
  12, 12, 12, 12,
  12, 12, 12, 12,

  12, 12, 12, 12,
  12, 12, 12, 12,
  12, 12, 12, 12,
  12, 12, 12, 12,

  9, 9, 9,
  12, 12, 12, 12,
  12, 12, 12, 12,
  12, 12, 12, 12,

  12, 12, 12, 12,
  12, 12, 12, 12,
  12, 12, 12, 12,
  12, 12, 12, 12,

  9, 9, 9,
  12, 12, 12, 12,
  12, 12, 12, 12,
  12, 12, 12, 12,
};

// här bestämmer jag vilken pin sakerna ska sitta på
const int ledPin = 13;
const int buttonPin = 4;
const int buzzerPin = 3;
int musikSpelar = 0;
int buttonState = 0;
int musik = 1;
int notlangd = 0;

void setup(void)
{
  pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT);//buzzer
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT); // knappen
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);// lampa på arduinon

}
void loop()
{


  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  if(digitalRead(buttonPin)==0){
    delay(10);
  }
  if(digitalRead(buttonPin)==1){
    sing(musik); //Här spelar jag musiken
    musikSpelar = 1; 
  }
  if(digitalRead(buttonPin)==0){
    delay(10);
  }
   if(musikSpelar == 1){
    //buzzer(melodyPin, 0, notlangd);
    musikSpelar = 0;
  }
}

void sing(int musik) {
  // upprepning av noterna i melodi:

    Serial.println(" 'Mario Theme'");
    int size = sizeof(melody) / sizeof(int);
    for (int Noten = 0; Noten < size; Noten++) {

      // för att räkna ut längden på noterna, tar man en sekund och dividerar på nottypen

      //vilket resuletar i att fjärde noten = 1000 / 4, åttonde noten = 1000/8, etc.

      notlangd = 1000 / tempo[Noten];

      buzzer(melodyPin, melody[Noten], notlangd);


      // för att hålla isär noterna, sätter jag ett minimum på tiden mellan dom.
      // notens längd + 30% ( va de som fungerade bäst:)
      int pausMellanTon = notlangd * 1.30;
      delay(pausMellanTon);

      // sluta spela tonerna:
      //buzzer(melodyPin, 0, notlangd);
    }   


}

void buzzer(int targetPin, long frekvens, long length) {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  long delayValue = 1000000 / frekvens / 2; 

  // räknar ut pausen mellan varje byte
  //// 1 sek i microsekunder, delat på frekvensen , sedan delat på hälften

  long numCycles = frekvens * length / 1000;

  // Beräkna antalet cykler för korrekt timing
  //// multiplisera frekvensen ,vilket egentligen är kretslopp per sekund, med antalet sekunder till
  //// det totala antalet "kretslopp"

  for (long i = 0; i < numCycles; i++) { // för den uträknade tiden...

    digitalWrite(targetPin, HIGH); // buzzern är på high för att den ska låta

    delayMicroseconds(delayValue); // vänta på den uträknade pausen

    digitalWrite(targetPin, LOW); // ha buzzern på pin low...

    delayMicroseconds(delayValue); // wait again or the calculated delay value
  }
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);

}
```

Comment: You need to explain your code, what it does, and the section you need help with. (Having comments in Swedish doesn't help most of your readers.)

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/InputPullupSerial